# React-query useInfiniteQuery: getNextPageParam not working

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm stuck using useInfiniteQuery.
The first call works fine, but the next page is not called with getNextPageParam

```js
const getProductItems = async (par) => {
  console.log("axios :", par);
  const res = await axios.get(`/api/v1/products`, {
    params: par,
  });

  return {
    result: res.data,
  };
};

export default function useGetProductItems(params) {
  const { data, isLoading, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage, isFetching } =
    useInfiniteQuery(
      ["getItems"],
      ({ pars = params }) => getProductItems(pars),
      {
        getNextPageParam: (res) => {
          console.log(res);
          const nextParams = {
            ...res.result.pageInfo,
            page: res.result.pageInfo.page + 1,
          };
          console.log("next :", nextParams);
          return nextParams;
        },
        select: (data) => {
          return data.pages[0].result.data;
        },
      }
    );

  return {
    data,
    isLoading,
    fetchNextPage,
    hasNextPage,
    isFetching,
  };
}
```

And the Query Client setting is like this

```js
export const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    },
  },
  queryCache: new QueryCache({
    onError: errorHandler,
  }),
  mutationCache: new MutationCache({
    onError: errorHandler,
  }),
});
```

As I am new to react-query, I am also wondering if there is any data that must be received from the API.

plz answer for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access `pageParam` and send it as argument to your fetching function. Also it'd be a good idea to check if there really is a next page before incrementing the actual page number in `getNextPageParam`. Something like this:

```
const { data, isLoading, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage, isFetching } =
  useInfiniteQuery(
    ['getItems'],
    ({ pageParam = 1 }) => getProductItems(pageParam), // pageParam defaults to the first page
    {
      getNextPageParam: lastPage => {
        return lastPage.result.pageInfo.page < lastPage.result.pageInfo.totalPages // Here I'm assuming you have access to the total number of pages
          ? lastPage.result.pageInfo.page + 1
          : undefined // If there is not a next page, getNextPageParam will return undefined and the hasNextPage boolean will be set to 'false'
      },
      select: data => {
        return data.pages[0].result.data
      },
    }
  )
```

I don't have information about how is your API endpoint built, but typically the request should look, for example, like this:

```
const getProductItems = async (page) => {
  const res = await axios.get(`/api/v1/products?page=${page}`);

  return {
    result: res.data,
  };
};
```